# How to draw primitives in Vulkan?

Tags: c++, graphics, rendering, vulkan

Assuming that Vulkan has already been initialized, you're recording to a command buffer, you have a frame buffer and a render pass, how does one draw primitive 2D geometric shapes using Vulkan?

```
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(command_buffer, &render_pass_info, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

// Draw primitives here

vkCmdEndRenderPass(command_buffer);
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. Answering this question would require explaining: shaders and shader compilation, pipeline state objects, pipelines, memory allocation, memory synchronization, memory uploading, buffers used for vertex input, and probably descriptor sets and/or push constants. This is simply too much for SO. There are plenty of pieces of example code out there; the Vulkan SDK comes with some.

Comment: I have not explored the totality of Vulkan examples available. But my first Google hit for "Vulkan single triangle example" turned up [this](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan), which seems perfectly serviceable. If you can't work around the fact that this example has color data, then I suspect that you're looking for something to copy-and-paste into your code, not something that you can actually learn from.

Comment: There are tons and tons and tons of examples on the web. Look at least the official websites: https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/ https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/ Don't forget LunarG and vendor sites (e.g. Nvidia)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The drawing setup is quite involved, but the actual calls required to draw are fairly straightforward. From the `tri.c` (which draws a 2D triangle):

```
// ...
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(demo->draw_cmd, &rp_begin, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
vkCmdBindPipeline(demo->draw_cmd, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
                              demo->pipeline);
vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(demo->draw_cmd, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, demo->pipeline_layout,
        0, 1, & demo->desc_set, 0, NULL);

VkViewport viewport = {};
viewport.height = (float) demo->height;
viewport.width = (float) demo->width;
viewport.minDepth = (float) 0.0f;
viewport.maxDepth = (float) 1.0f;
vkCmdSetViewport(demo->draw_cmd, 0, 1, &viewport);

VkRect2D scissor = {};
scissor.extent.width = demo->width;
scissor.extent.height = demo->height;
scissor.offset.x = 0;
scissor.offset.y = 0;
vkCmdSetScissor(demo->draw_cmd, 0, 1, &scissor);

VkDeviceSize offsets[1] = {0};
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(demo->draw_cmd, VERTEX_BUFFER_BIND_ID, 1, &demo->vertices.buf, offsets);

vkCmdDraw(demo->draw_cmd, 3, 1, 0, 0);
vkCmdEndRenderPass(demo->draw_cmd);
// ...
```

This snippet assumes that you've already gotten the `VkPipeline` (which include shaders, etc.), `VkBuffer` (for the vertex buffer), and the `VkCommandBuffer` in appropriate states. It's the `vkCmdDraw` that actually issues the command to draw, once the containing `VkCommandBuffer` is executed.